# show that this function is linear

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

let $g$ be continuous on the unit circle such that $g(-x) = -g(x)$ define $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = |x| g(x/\|x\|)$ if $x \not= 0$ and $0$ otherwise. Show that the function $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $h(t) = f(tx)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R^2}$ is differentiable.

The question does it by saying $h$ is linear, since $g(-x) = -g(x)$ but I don't see how that implies it's linear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
h(t) = f(tx)=|tx| g(tx/\|tx\|).
$$
For $t>0$ we obtain
$$
|tx|=t|x|,\quad g(tx/\|tx\|)=g(x/\|x\|)
$$
and so $$h(t)=t|x| g(x/\|x\|).$$ For $t<0$, using that $g(-x)=-g(x)$ we obtain
$$
|tx|=-t|x|,\quad g(tx/\|tx\|)=-g(x/\|x\|)
$$
and so again $$h(t)=t|x| g(x/\|x\|).$$ Therefore,
$$
h(t)=t|x| g(x/\|x\|)=th(1)
$$
for any $t\ne0$. So $h$ is indeed linear.

Comment: how did you get rid of the $t$ inside $g$? and why does that use $g(-x) = -g(x)$

Comment: @realanalysis Just added the details to my answer.

Comment: perfect, thanks!